# Fourier transform of a sum

Tags: fourier-transform, power-spectral-density, linear-phase

I have a function :
\begin{equation}
C(t)=\left(1.42*\exp^{-1.192t}- 12.44*\exp^{-1.192t} +11.02 \right) u(t)
\end{equation}
where u(t) is a unit-step function
What is its fourier transform? a step by step breakdown would greatly be appreciated: notably how would you manage the fact that it is a summation, would the linearity of a fourier property apply? How would you compute the power and the phase of the sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would the linearity of a fourier property apply?

Of course, why not?

> How would you compute the power and the phase of the sum?

Computing each term in complex numbers, summing and converting to power/phase representation

> a step by step breakdown would greatly be appreciated

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
C(t)&=\left(1.42 \exp^{-1.192t}- 12.44 \exp^{-1.192t} +11.02 \right) u(t) \\
 & = 1.42 \exp^{-1.192t} u(t) - 12.44 \exp^{-1.192t} u(t) +11.02 u(t)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}(C(t)) = 1.42 \mathcal{F}\left( \exp^{-1.192t} u(t)\right) - 12.44 \mathcal{F}\left(\exp^{-1.192t} u(t)\right) + 11.02\mathcal{F}\left( u(t)\right)
\end{equation}

Can you go from here? And why aren't you summing your exponential terms?

Comment: Yes I can take it from here on.....what do you mean but why not sum my exponentials they are not products here or do you mean something else?

Comment: I just saw what you meant by summing , my mistake the second exponential exponent is -0,136*t...unfortunately I don't have the privileges to edit my own question per stackexchange Policy can somebody do it?

Comment: So here is what I found as F(C(t)), could you please confirm if it checks out : 
F(C(t))=   1.42/(1.192+j*w)   -  12.44/(0.136+j*w)    +11.02 F(u(t))

Answer (score 0):

Fourier transform is a linear filter [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransform.html). Linearity means:

`F[ax+by] = aF[x] + bF[y]`

for any constants a and b, and for any signal/variable/function x and y. So of course, the linearity applies to your signal C(t).

For a signal of form

`exp(-at)u(t)`

its Fourier transform is readily available [See Page 3](https://uspas.fnal.gov/materials/11ODU/FourierTransformPairs.pdf).